# How to use Picasso in android where image is sourced by HTTP posting to a URL

Tags: android, http, url, post, picasso

I'm using the Picasso utils in Android however I am stuck when trying to load an image from a URL.

The issue is that the URL is a php page which generates the image. The URL requires that a HTTP post (containing username/password and other id info) of certain parameters are made to it, and it returns the image.

How can I go about this? Please note I don't want to use a GET (or ?query parameters as don't want the username/pass supplied in the url directly for security.

Comment: Even if you wanted to make a GET request it would not work because as you told a POST has to be done.

Comment: yep - it needs to be a POST request (i did read somewhere that picasso passes query params as  post params too but not sure if thats true)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - somehow  - merged asynchttpclient with picasso and used the file in picasso

```
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();




    ScriptsRequestor.post("URL",params,"Download photo: " + memberID + " (PHOTO "+ photoNumber + ")",new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(context){

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, File response) {
            // use the file
            Picasso.with(context).load(response).placeholder(R.drawable.loading).error(R.drawable.loading).into(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header [] headers,Throwable throwable, File error){

            //some error getting photo
            Log.d("LOG", "Error downloading photo: " + statusCode + " " + throwable.getMessage());


        }

    });
```